# How to create dynamic link in views?

Tags: views, nodes

I am using views and I want to put a dynamic link in the header. The link is http://www.example.com/node/add/album/31
The number 31 varies depending which node it is viewing so I want it to change to whatever node id it is viewing. I'm not a coder so can anyone give me code?

Comment: Please consider marking some answers to your questions as 'Accepted'.  You __and__ the community will benefit in the long run

Answer (score 1):

you can add a "global text area" field to the "header" of the view. Then add the link HTML in there:

```
<a href="node/add/album/%1">add</a>
```

The %1 will take the the first argument from the URL

Answer (score 0):

you need to make a menu item with the name 'node/add/album/%'

```
function YOURMODULENAME_menu() {

    $items['node/add/album/%'] = array(       
        'page callback' => 'YOURMODULENAME_YOURFUNCTNAME',
        'page arguments' => array(3),
        'access callback' => TRUE,
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    );

    return $items;
}
```

Then you need the function and you would print the title as well as the your view in this callback function

```
function YOURMODULENAME_YOURFUNCTNAME()
{
    $nid = arg(3);
    $node = node_load($nid);
    $title = $node->title;

    $content = '<p><a href="node/add/album/'.$nid.'">'.$title.'</a></p>';
    $content.= views_embed_view('YOURVIEWNAME', 'default');
    return $content;
}
```

There can be many solutions to it, the code is untested, let me know if there is any issue in it.
Firdous